# Apply optim function on iteratively each row of dataframe

Tags: r, loops, iteration, vectorization

I have a working `optim` function that works for a single row.

The `optim` function estimates mineral proportions from chemical data by minimizing the residuals.

I would like to apply the same function for each row in the dataframe (in reality there may be a large amount of rows).

I've tried using rowwise from `dplyr` but it is not correct.

Data:

Dataframe below of ideal mineral compositions:

```
Min_comp <- tibble::tribble(
  ~SiO2, ~TiO2, ~Al2O3, ~Fe2O3, ~MnO, ~MgO, ~CaO, ~Na2O, ~K2O, ~P2O5, ~CO2,   ~S,
    100,     0,      0,      0,    0,    0,    0,     0,    0,     0,    0,    0,
   64.8,     0,   18.3,      0,    0,    0,    0,     0, 16.9,     0,    0,    0,
      0,     0,      0,      0,    0,    0, 54.7,     0,    0,  41.7,    0,    0,
      0,     0,      0, 103.45,    0,    0,    0,     0,    0,     0,    0,    0,
   51.4,     0,      0,   42.7,    0,    0,    0,   6.6,    0,     0,    0,    0,
      0,     0,      0,   17.9,    0, 10.1,   28,     0,    0,     0,    0,    0,
      0,     0,      0,   66.6,    0,    0,    0,     0,    0,     0,    0, 53.4
  )
```

Initial estimates of mineral proportions

```
Min_Est <- tibble::tribble(
              ~Quartz, ~K.feldspar, ~Apatite, ~Magnetite, ~Riebeckite, ~Ankerite, ~Pyrite,
                 39.4,         4.3,        0,       25.4,         9.3,       4.9,       0
             )
```

Actual chemical composition:

```
Act_comp <- tibble::tribble(
              ~SiO2, ~TiO2, ~Al2O3, ~Fe2O3, ~MnO, ~MgO, ~CaO, ~Na2O, ~K2O, ~P2O5, ~CO2,   ~S, 
              46.91,  0.02,   0.88,   31.2, 0.05, 2.33, 0.73,  0.62, 0.61,  0.25,    0, 0.05
              )
```

Function to be optimized (working for single row):

```
Mineral_Estimation_opt <- function(MinProp, par, Actual){

  return(sum(Actual-(colSums(as.matrix(MinProp/100*par[1:7]))))^2)
  
}
```

Optimization of function

```
# start parameters 

start <- c(40,5, 3, 30, 5, 1, 3) # estimate realistic parameters 
                                 # order of values qtz, k.feld, apatite, magnetite, riebeckite, ankerite, pyrite

result <- optim(par = start, fn = Mineral_Estimation_opt, MinProp = Min_comp, Actual = Act_comp,method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0), upper = c(100), control = list(maxit = 1000))
 
result
```

The above code works, now an example where there is more than one row of data in the Act_comp dataframe:

```
Act_comp_rows <- tibble::tribble(
   ~SiO2, ~TiO2, ~Al2O3, ~Fe2O3,  ~MnO,  ~MgO,  ~CaO, ~Na2O,  ~K2O, ~P2O5, ~CO2,    ~S,
  48.707, 0.027,  1.395,  27.81, 0.079, 3.577, 0.863, 0.297, 0.308,  0.15,   0L, 0.062,
  49.324, 0.018,  0.559,  30.98, 0.016, 2.115, 0.621, 0.567, 0.461,  0.31,   0L, 0.017,
  46.919, 0.021,  0.955,  31.35,  0.07, 2.688, 0.547, 0.566, 0.572, 0.303,   0L, 0.032
  )
```

I can get the residual of the data for each row of the data frame by adding rowSums:

```
Mineral_Estimation_opt <- function(MinProp, par, Actual){

  return(rowSums(Actual-(colSums(as.matrix(MinProp/100*par[1:7]))))^2)
  
}

result <- optim(par = start, fn = Mineral_Estimation_opt, MinProp = min_comp1, Actual = act_comp1,method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0), upper = c(100), control = list(maxit = 1000))
```

However, when trying to rerun the `optim` function it returns the error

> Error in optim(par = start, fn = Mineral_Estimation_opt, MinProp = Min_comp,  :
> objective function in optim evaluates to length 3 not 1

Due to it not calculating rowwise.

What is the best way to calculate this function for each row of the dataframe.

Many thanks

Matt

Comment: The code you show is not working. There is one error at `Actual = act_comp1`, easy to fix with `Act_comp`, but there is a second error I cannot fix: `MinProp = min_comp1`. Does it have to be replaced by `Min_Est`?

Comment: Apologies, changed the variable names so they are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `purrr::map` and iterate over the lines of `Min_comp`.

`results` will be a list with the result for each line.

```
results <- purrr::map(
        seq_len(nrow(Min_comp)),
           function(line_nb) {
                start <- c(40,5, 3, 30, 5, 1, 3)                        
                optim(par = start,
                      fn = Mineral_Estimation_opt,
                      MinProp = Min_comp,
                      Actual = Min_comp[line_nb,],
                      method = "L-BFGS-B",
                      lower = c(0),
                      upper = c(100),
                      control = list(maxit = 1000))})
```

The `map` function works as a loop but at the same time it collects the outputs of each iteration as a list.

Comment: If it's not too much too ask, could you give a brief explanation of how this works? I can roughly follow why but I doubt I could explain it to anyone.